# Merge algorithm with arrays split in c>2 ways

Tags: recursion, asymptotic-complexity

As an example question we are asked to create a variant of merge sort where it splits array in to `c>2` arrays of roughly equal size (when `c = 2` it will use regular merge)

This is the solution:

```
 cmerge(a1, a2, .... ac)
    if c = 2 return Merge(a1, a2)
     else 
     b1 = cmerge(a1, a2,...a(c/2), floor(c/2))
     b2 = cmerge(a(roof(c/2)),... ac, roof(c/2))
     return merge(b1,b2)
```

I understand where they got this solution but when it asks for the reccurrnce relationi get a bit confused. in the question they state c sorted arrays can be merged in `O(n log c)`
which makes the first case clear

```
T(n) = c(T(n/c)) + nlogc if n>= c
T(n) = theta(n^2) for n<c   <----------- can someone explain where they are getting this?
```

I just reallly don't get where the `n^2` is coming from. In the second case is there not just one call to MERGE? And merge is `theta(n)` if I remember.

Comment: apparently I also dont know how to post code -.-